# How to download a PDF file on a web page in Python

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download the PDF file in the link below in Python.

[Link](https://www.osapublishing.org/view_article.cfm?gotourl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eosapublishing%2Eorg%2FDirectPDFAccess%2F42C574A0-ABB6-FD11-777A24C1C4C5ADEF_274099%2Foe-21-22-27371%2Epdf%3Fda%3D1%26id%3D274099%26seq%3D0%26mobile%3Dno&org=)

I tried to download it, but couldn't open the file saved.
My PDF viewer gave "The format of source is not PDF."
Could someone tell me what is wrong?

```
import urllib2

def main():
    url = "https://www.osapublishing.org/view_article.cfm?gotourl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eosapublishing%2Eorg%2FDirectPDFAccess%2F42C574A0-ABB6-FD11-777A24C1C4C5ADEF_274099%2Foe-21-22-27371%2Epdf%3Fda%3D1%26id%3D274099%26seq%3D0%26mobile%3Dno&org="
    download_file("example", url)

def download_file(file_name, download_url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open(file_name + ".pdf", 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
    print("Completed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is *not* a link to a PDF but to an HTML frame that contains the PDF. Use the direct URL instead:

```
url = "http://www.osapublishing.org/DirectPDFAccess/42C574A0-ABB6-FD11-777A24C1C4C5ADEF_274099/oe-21-22-27371.pdf?da=1&id=274099&seq=0&mobile=no"
```

You can obtain the source of the PDF file by viewing the HTML source of your original link.